# Fire an event only when an focused element looses focus

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my Fiddle [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7jTGY/7/)

```
$(function() {
    $('.glyphicon-edit').click(function () {
        $(this).parent().find('.form-control').removeAttr("readonly").focus();
    });
    $('.form-control:focus').blur(function() {
        $(this).addAttr("readonly");
    });
});
```

What I am trying to do?
  I am trying to create a dynamically editable form.It should have

When someone click on edit icon, the corresponding Input field should get focussed and become editable. (I completed this part).

Next i want is when an element is in focus state and it looses focus then i want to add readonly attribute again to that element. This part in not working. can somebody explain me why. and give a solution for it

EDIT:
 In the later part i was trying alert("some msg") to check whether the event is getting fired or not. while posting i just replaced it with addAttr. it was a typo

Comment: But why? What's the point of having a read-only input when it's no longer read-only on focus ?

Comment: Its a kind of review form. just to show what user filled already. i am providing a edit button if user want to change his info. but dont want it to get focus on some random click

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use instead:

### --DEMO--

```
$(function () {
    $('.glyphicon-edit').click(function () {
        $(this).parent().find('.form-control').prop("readonly", false).focus().one('blur', function () {
            $(this).prop('readonly', true);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Need, bit more help. I want the edit button to go off, when someone click it, letting the readonly to true and on blur i want the edit to appear again

Comment: Yea, thanks a ton. I was trying but i was not getting. i will learn from your code

Answer (score 1):

There is no `addAttr()` function. The setter for `attr` looks like this:

```
$('.form-control').blur(function() {
    $(this).attr("readonly", true);
});
```

Also, the `:focus` psuedo selector here is redundant, as to fire the `blur` event the element *has* to have focus in the first place.

Comment: Minor nitpick: in modern jQuery this should either be `attr("readonly", "readonly")` or `prop("readonly", true)`.